# Get sub-catalogs from registry

Tags: c#, registry, catalog

Can someone suggest good way, how to get all subcategories from the registry?

**Example:** I have `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\AnyName\\` in the registry and there are some catalogs so how to get list all of them in string?

Comment: I know how to get paticular data from registry, but no idea about list of name of cataloges

Comment: Have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getsubkeynames.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure I understand your question but if you want the sub key names you can do:

```
string[] subKeyNames = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("AnyName").GetSubKeyNames();
```

There are lots of examples on the web for using the Registry class - also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) has some samples and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Just enumerate sub-keys using [`GetSubKeyNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getsubkeynames.aspx).